# Skip chain of CompletableFuture based on a specific condition

Tags: java-8, completable-future

There are several CompletionFutures methods that I'd like to chain. The problem is that I want to skip other chain and go to last method of the pipeline if some condition is met. Mentioned as comment in the below code. For example:

```
    public CompletableFuture<Void> process() {
            CompletableFuture<Set<String>> service1 = new CompletableFuture();
            return service1
                    .thenCompose(data -> {
                        if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                            SomeObject obj = prepareSomeObject();
                            obj.addAll(data.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    //Here want to check some condition and if it meets, then go to last method of the pipeline
    //Otherwise continue with the current flow
                            CompletableFuture<String> someFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
                            CompletableFuture<String> someOtherFuture= new CompletableFuture<>();
                            return CompletableFuture.allOf(someFuture, someOtherFuture)
                                    .thenApply(aVoid -> {
                                        String user = someFuture.join();
                                        String unit = someOtherFuture.join();
                                        obj.setUnit(unit);
                                        obj.setUser(user)
                                        return obj;
                                    })
                                    .thenCompose(this::someMethod)
                                    .thenCompose(this::someOtherMethod); // last method in the pipeline
                        }
                        return completedFuture(null);
                    });
        }
```

I have tried something like this, Please critique on the right way to do it.

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> process() {
        CompletableFuture<Set<String>> service1 = new CompletableFuture();
        return service1
                .thenCompose(data -> {
                    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                        SomeObject obj = prepareSomeObject();
                        obj.addAll(data.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
                        if(condition not match) { //condition match
                        CompletableFuture<String> someFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
                        CompletableFuture<String> someOtherFuture= new CompletableFuture<>();
                        return CompletableFuture.allOf(someFuture, someOtherFuture)
                                .thenApply(aVoid -> {
                                    String user = someFuture.join();
                                    String unit = someOtherFuture.join();
                                    obj.setUnit(unit);
                                    obj.setUser(user)
                                })
                                .thenCompose(this::someMethod)
                                .thenCompose(this::someOtherMethod); // last method in the pipeline
                         } else return someOtherMethod(obj);
                    }
                    return completedFuture(null);
                });
    }
```

Comment: There is a contradiction in `thenCompose(this::someOtherMethod)` and `return someOtherMethod();`. One time, the method has a parameter, the other time, it has not. Further, it’s not clear why these steps depend on `someOtherFuture` when its result is never used.

Comment: I have updated the question. someOtherFuture has no significant role here. Also someOtherMethod has the parameter.

Comment: Why are you constructing a dependency like `CompletableFuture.allOf(someFuture, someOtherFuture)` when “`someOtherFuture` has no significant role here”? Why not just `someFuture.thenAccept(obj::setUser)`? Why does in one case `someMethod` provide the arguments to `someOtherMethod`, but in the other, there’s an `arguments` coming out of nowhere? Apparently, the `SomeObject` you’re constructing upfront does not appear in the result at all, at least in the second case when you are returning `someOtherMethod(arguments)`.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am trying to skip some of the parameters being set to 'obj' and return the last method of pipeline when certain condition does not match.